# Efficient way to clear areas in Excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project with VBA in which I have to clear a large area. I currently do this with a for-each loop as shown below. Is there a more efficient/faster way to do this? I'm not sure if this is possible.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wsTest.Range("I5:NP83")
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "test" Then
            cell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next cell
```

I've already tried using two nested for loops instead of the for-each loop and using a `cell.ClearContents` instead of `cell.Value = ""` but neither is faster.

Comment: Assign the `rng.Formula` to an array, manipulate that, then write it back?

Comment: Not `rng.Formula`, `rng.Value`

Comment: Is `test` the result of a formula?  Or is it just sitting there as plain text?

Comment: @FunThomas It depends. `.Value` would overwrite all formulas in the range. That may not be what is wanted.

Comment: Thank you all. The tip with the array was very strong, I didn't even think of it.

Comment: Have you tried including `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of your program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Increase Efficiency Vastly By Utilizing Arrays

```vb
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = wsTest.Range("I5:NP83")
Dim Data(): Data = rng.Value

Dim r As Long, c As Long

For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
        If CStr(Data(r, c)) <> "test" Then Data(r, c) = Empty
    Next c
Next r
  
rng.Value = Data
```

Comment: As @Rory comment, what about assigning the `rng.Formula` to an array, manipulate that, then write it back, `rng.Value` would overwrite all formulas in the range.,That may not be what is wanted by OP

Comment: @Soma I'm not considering it due to the following: OP wants to clear everything that is not *"test"*. What if *"test"* is the result of a formula? Then it won't be found. Also, you usually don't mix formulas and values in single columns.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is faster

```
Sub clearRg()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("I5:NP83")
    
    rg.Name = "a"
    Range("a") = Evaluate("IF(a<>""test"","""",a)")
    rg.Name.Delete
End Sub
```

**PS** This will also work in case *test* is the result of a formula, i.e the formula will remain intact.

**PPS1**  I conducted a speed comparison between the array solution and the Evaluate method, and both perform at an identical speed of ~0.08 seconds on my computer.

**PPS2** The speed test outcome for the OP's solution, involving access to the worksheet, is approximately 0.9 seconds without disabling ScreenUpdating. With ScreenUpdating disabled, the time decreases to around 0.6 seconds.